# How can I co-sort two Vecs based on the values in one of the Vecs?

Tags: rust

I have two `Vec`s that correspond to a list of feature vectors and their corresponding class labels, and I'd like to co-sort them by the class labels.

However, Rust's `sort_by` operates on a slice rather than being a generic function over a trait (or similar), and the closure only gets the elements to be compared rather than the indices so I can sneakily hack the sort to be parallel.

I've considered the solution:

```
let mut both = data.iter().zip(labels.iter()).collect();
both.sort_by( blah blah );
// Now split them back into two vectors
```

I'd prefer not to allocate a whole new vector to do this every time because the size of the data can be extremely large.

I can always implement my own sort, of course, but if there's a builtin way to do this it would be much better.

Comment: I suppose there's good reason to not have a vector of structs where each struct contains a feature and a class?

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm passing it into libsvm which requires them to be separate, so unfortunately yes.

Comment: One way to minimise allocations is to only allocate a vector of indices (if you'll have fewer than 4 billion elements, they only need to be `u32`, so 4 bytes per elem) and sort that via `sort_by` indexing into `labels`. The result can then be used to permute `data` and `labels` into the right order. (Unfortunately still allocates O(n) memory, of course.)

Comment: As `sort_by` doesn’t do it itself, you’d need to implement the sorting yourself, probably using `sort_by` as the basis. Oh, and it *can’t* just give you the indices, because they’re not constant. If you really were to insist on using `sort_by`, you’d need to do pointer comparison to get the index of an element in the slice and then figure out what `sort_by` is going to do with your response and do it to the other vector yourself, which would be an utterly mad and fragile way of doing it. So yeah, just look at what `sort_by` does and copy it.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: For clarification, the point about indices not being constant is that when you are going to shuffle the label and data vectors by reading the sorted indices vector, then after the first shuffle the indices are no longer referring to the same items they were before. Or is it something else?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/benashford/rust-lazysort ? It still allocates, but the iterator abstraction might help allocate less with less code, I don't know.

Comment: Note that `sort_by` already allocates 2n space, so you're not going to avoid allocation unless you use a different sorting function.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: correct, [as in this example](http://is.gd/Z5QowO). Note how the addresses of `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` vary from comparison to comparison.

Comment: @WillFischer: Ouch, that hurts. Do you know why such allocation was chosen? I know that in C++ for example, `std::sort` specifically avoids allocating.

Comment: `[T]::sort/sort_by` is a stable sort. There are alternatives on crates.io if you need a non-stable nonallocating sort.

Comment: @Matthieu It looks like C++'s stable sort also allocates, but it's capable of falling back on a non-allocating less efficient algorithm. Rust currently has much worse support for allocation failure, so I'm not surprised that it doesn't have that fallback. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort

Comment: @bluss: Ah! I did not know it was stable, nice.

Answer (score 17):

I just wrote [a crate "permutation"](https://crates.io/crates/permutation) that allows you to do this :)

```
let names = vec!["Bob", "Steve", "Jane"];
let salary = vec![10, 5, 15];
let permutation = permutation::sort(&salary);
let ordered_names = permutation.apply_slice(&names);
let ordered_salaries = permutation.apply_slice(&salary);
assert!(ordered_names == vec!["Steve", "Bob", "Jane"]);
assert!(ordered_salaries == vec![5, 10, 15]);
```

It likely will support this in a single function call in the future.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Rust community. For my purposes, it's a shame that this is licensed under the GPL and not MIT / Apache, like the majority of Rust libraries.

Comment: I have updated the license to be dual licensed under Apache / MIT, like Rust is.

Comment: Unfortunately this is quite slow as applying the permutation now involves random access reads whereas sorting is using mostly localized memory access.

Comment: @orlp do you have a benchmark or is this just speculation?