# Is there a way to shuffle two or more lists in the same order?

Tags: rust

I want something like this pseudocode:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
b = [3, 4, 5, 6];
iter = a.iter_mut().zip(b.iter_mut());
shuffle(iter);
// example shuffle:
// a = [2, 4, 3, 1];
// b = [4, 6, 5, 3];
```

More specifically, is there some function which performs like:

```
fn shuffle<T>(iterator: IterMut<T>) { /* ... */ }
```

My specific case is trying to shuffle an `Array2` by rows and a vector `(array2:Lndarray:Array2<f32>, vec:Vec<usize>)`.

Specifically `array2.iter_axis(Axis(1)).zip(vec.iter())`.

Comment: What does shuffle do? Randomly shuffles all elements?

Comment: Yes, like: https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.shuffle.

Comment: You could shuffle a list of indices and then use these to define new lists?

Comment: @JohannesAck That does work and could be implemented for a specific case, but it doesn't generalise to allow shuffling of any `T:Iterator` structs.

Comment: shuffle an iterator don't make any sense.

Comment: @Stargateur I'm not sure how else I could specify it would apply to any iterable struct.

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light how would you implement it ? stock all item from the inner iterator into a temporary vector and shuffle it ? that would be very inefficient

Comment: The function you linked to shuffles slices, not iterators. I know shuffling iterator ranges makes sense in some languages (like C++, which has random access iterators), but Rust iterators are much more narrowly defined.

Comment: @Stargateur I don't know, I'm just defining the goal. The implementation is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: See also [How can I co-sort two Vecs based on the values in one of the Vecs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32564455/155423)

Comment: I guess shuffling could be generalized for types implementing `IndexMut<usize>`.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling a generic iterator in-place is not possible.

However, it's pretty easy to implement shuffling for a slice:

```
use rand::Rng;

pub fn shufflex<T: Copy>(slice: &mut [T]) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let len = slice.len();
    for i in 0..len {
        let next = rng.gen_range(i, len);
        let tmp = slice[i];
        slice[i] = slice[next];
        slice[next] = tmp;
    }
}
```

But it's also possible to write a more general `shuffle` function that works on many types:

```
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};
use rand::Rng;

pub fn shuffle<T>(indexable: &mut T)
where
    T: IndexMut<usize> + Len + ?Sized,
    T::Output: Copy,
{
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let len = indexable.len();
    for i in 0..len {
        let next = rng.gen_range(i, len);
        let tmp = indexable[i];
        indexable[i] = indexable[next];
        indexable[next] = tmp;
    }
}
```

I wrote a complete example that also allows shuffling across multiple slices in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bde6557d4f4185176f9ba0b0ed26e52f).

**EDIT**: I think I misunderstood what you want to do. To shuffle several slices in the same way, I would do [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=133122d952755c9ea3a7d0f5ab3ee0a7):

```
use rand::Rng;

pub fn shuffle<T: Copy>(slices: &mut [&mut [T]]) {
    if slices.len() > 0 {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

        let len = slices[0].len();
        assert!(slices.iter().all(|s| s.len() == len));

        for i in 0..len {
            let next = rng.gen_range(i, len);

            for slice in slices.iter_mut() {
                let tmp: T = slice[i];
                slice[i] = slice[next];
                slice[next] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) would allow your code to work even if `T` is not `Copy`.

Comment: @Jmb I tried this, but it would require mutably borrowing the slice twice. Do you know a simple solution that doesn't require `unsafe`?

Comment: There is [`slice::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap)

Comment: @Aloso Also, mutably borrowing disjoint pieces of a slice is [possible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut).

Answer (score 0):

To shuffle in the same order, you can first remember the order and then reuse it for every shuffle. Starting with the Fisher-Yates shuffle from the [rand crate](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/src/rand/seq/mod.rs.html#453):

```rust
fn shuffle<R>(&mut self, rng: &mut R)
where R: Rng + ?Sized {
    for i in (1..self.len()).rev() {
        self.swap(i, gen_index(rng, i + 1));
    }
}
```

It turns out that we need to store random numbers between 0 and `i + 1` for each `i` between 1 and the length of the slice, in reverse order:

```rust
// create a vector of indices for shuffling slices of given length
let indices: Vec<usize> = {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    (1..slice_len).rev()
    .map(|i| rng.gen_range(0, i + 1))
    .collect()
};
```

Then we can implement a variant of shuffle where, instead of generating new random numbers, we pick them up from the above list of random indices:

```rust
// shuffle SLICE taking indices from the provided vector
for (i, &rnd_ind) in (1..slice.len()).rev().zip(&indices) {
    slice.swap(i, rnd_ind);
}
```

Putting the two together, you can shuffle multiple slices in the same order using a method like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff390112acbfe1188e6b4438107ca419)):

```rust
pub fn shuffle<T>(slices: &mut [&mut [T]]) {
    if slices.len() == 0 {
        return;
    }
    let indices: Vec<usize> = {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        (1..slices[0].len())
            .rev()
            .map(|i| rng.gen_range(0, i + 1))
            .collect()
    };
    for slice in slices {
        assert_eq!(slice.len(), indices.len() + 1);
        for (i, &rnd_ind) in (1..slice.len()).rev().zip(&indices) {
            slice.swap(i, rnd_ind);
        }
    }
}
```