# Sort a slice based on keys in another slice without allocating

Tags: sorting, rust

This is not a duplicate of [How can I co-sort two Vecs based on the values in one of the Vecs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564455/how-can-i-co-sort-two-vecs-based-on-the-values-in-one-of-the-vecs), because the `permutation` crate's implementation allocates.

How can I sort a slice based on the contents of another slice without allocating?

```rust
slice1 = [
    AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD
]

slice2 = [
    12, -3, 6, 17
]
```

Result:

```rust
[BBB, CCC, AAA, DDD]
```

Both `slice1` and `slice2` are not too large (integers, at most about 1 KiB, usually much smaller), but this sort could be done very often. It is not required to preserve `slice2`, so it could be implemented by sorting `slice2` and performing the same operations on `slice1` at the same time, but any sorting implementation I made would perform poorer than the standard library implementation.

Comment: Are you sure that allocations are your bottleneck? Can you pre-allocate a buffer and reuse it in each iteration?

Comment: The standard library doesn't take preallocated buffers.

Comment: Only possibility I can see is to hand-roll your own in-place sort working on both vecs concurrently, without allocation. Note that because your "sort keys" vec is an integer array, you might be able to use a non-comparison sort. Alternatively, vendor the stdlib's quicksort and modify it for your use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library sorting algorithm is accessible via three methods:

- `[T]::sort`
- `[T]::sort_by` (takes `FnMut(&T, &T) -> Ordering` as comperator)
- `[T]::sort_by_key` (takes `FnMut(&T) -> K`)

The latter two are important when you want any kind of non-standard sorting behavior. But as you can see, you only get access to the elements of the slice you are sorting.

<s>Well, you *could* take that reference `&T`, convert it into a raw pointer, subtract the slice base from it and tada: you have the index! With the index you could take a look into the other array.</s> (edit: nope, see comments.) *However*, this only works until the first two elements are swapped by the algorithm. You would have to duplicate all swaps in the integer array as well. And the standard library simply does not offer you to "get notified" about the swaps.

So as far as I can see it: in your scenario, you have to either allocate or write the sorting algorithm yourself.

---

In case allocation is not a hard limit, but merely a performance consideration: you should measure that.

One easy way I could think of:

```
let mut vec = slice2.iter().zip(slice1).collect::<Vec<_>>();
vec.sort();
```

With that, you get `[(-3, BBB), (6, CCC), (12, AAA), (17, DDD)]` as result. You can of course easily pick only the second element from that. There are a bunch of alternative solutions, of course.

Comment: _"Well, you could take that reference &T, convert it into a raw pointer, subtract the slice base from it and tada: you have the index!"_ This does not work. The standard library is perfectly allowed to move an element out of your slice into a temporary local and then call your function on a reference to this local variable.